# warning: passing argument 2 of ‘getsockname’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, tcp

I can't figure this out. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error:

`warning: passing argument 2 of ‘getsockname’ from incompatible pointer type`

In the following code:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main() {
  int sd;
  struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

  bzero(&my_addr,sizeof(my_addr));
  my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  my_addr.sin_port = htons(0);
  my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  socklen_t my_addr_size = sizeof my_addr;

  if((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Cannot create socket for master socket.\n");
            fprintf(stdout, "Terminating program\n\n");
                exit(1);
  }

  if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) < 0) {
        fprintf (stdout, "Binding failed for master socket\n\n");
            perror("bind failed");
                exit (1);
  }

  if (getsockname(sd, &my_addr, &my_addr_size) == -1) {
        perror("getsockname() failed");
            return -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument to `getsockname` should be a `struct sockaddr *`.  You're passing the address of a `struct sockaddr_in`.

Comment: Thank you! That argument just needs a cast to `struct sockaddr *`.